# How to maximize a minimized window in Windows 10 IoT Core

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, windows-10-iot-core

I am currently working on a project for Windows 10 IoT Core (*my first*).

It is basicly an **Universal Windows Platform Application** (c#) to **run on Windows IoT** and give the user some basic options to control the system ( e.g. execute PowerShell-Scripts, Copy files from USB-Device etc.). The user should be able to start a view programms from this "Shell" as well. Because Windows 10 IoT Core **doesn't have a Task-Bar**, how do i **handle Windows** that were **minimized by the user**?

Does anyone have experiences with this topic?

**Edit:** The Goal is not possible to be achieved like described above!

Comment: Does Win10 IoT Core have Windows? I thought it was a single-app single-window UWP application.

Comment: Yes, @Mitch, you are completely right! I guess i wont be able to achieve my Goals like this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 IoT does not have a taskbar.  When it boots, it boots directly into a single UWP application.  There is no facility for multi-tasking, because there is no multi-tasking.

If you want to provide a task-switcher, you will have to write one yourself.  A `TabControl` might be a rudimentary option.

Comment: Windows 10 IoT Core seems to only be able to run a single "Headed" (UI)Application. This means a TabControl isn't an option either. [Developing Apps for Windows IoT](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/buildingappsforiotcore)

Comment: A TabControl is just a set of buttons with a ContentPresenter.  Nothing prevents you from writing a "shell" that way.  Packaging is a different topic, but what you describe its achievable.

Comment: It seems like my question wasn't completely clear. I wanted to execute another application on the press of a button and was looking for a way to maximize this application after the user would have minimized it. So basicly rebuild the Windows Task-Bar!

Comment: Ok.  What part of that do you think you cannot do?  You can write a program (a shell) which opens a "window" for powershell, a "window" for [an exe included in the appx](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/samples/externalprocesslauncher), a file explorer, your LOB apps, etc...

Comment: To "rebuild" a Task-Bar (display running applications and theire windows) i need to retireve a list of running applications. Does UWP (.net core) provide the ability to do this?

Comment: Windows 10 IoT Core can only run one Headed Application simultaneously, so there is a single window on the home page. You could reference the homepage of IoTCoreDefaultApp running on RP3. There are some buttons like device information, command line and tutorials.